# VMware installed but cant open

Tags: 13.04, command-line

I installed the .bundle file via sudo sh VMware-Workstation-Full-9.0.2-1031769.x86_64.bundle

how do I open the file once I've installed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the "Start Workstation" chapter of the [Getting Started with VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/desktop/ws90-getting-started.pdf) documentation.

Then keep reading.

VMware Workstation is a fairly complicated system. If you don't yet have the skills to figure out how to launch it, you're going to have a very hard time setting it up and keeping it working without reading the docs.